# run shell command for third party application, pass file arguements

Tags: c#, .net, shell

I'm trying to edit my own shell command to include another shell command from another application, namely `AxCrypt`. In a sense I'm trying to merge two context menu actions into one. If I right-click on a file, I go to `AxCrypt` and choose "Encrypt file to .EXE". Then I right-click again on the encrypted file and choose my shell command.

The reason I'm being so specific is someone may have something like this already. I have added this:

```
try
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Axantum\AxCrypt\AxCrypt.exe";
  proc.Start();
  MessageBox.Show("AxCrypt run");
}...
```

I get my messagebox, but the `AxCrypt` application doesn't run. any ideas on how to

1. determine if the executable i've entered is the right one for the context menu selection in windows
2. correctly run this process and feed it the file argument for the file that i clicked on (as if i had chosen their menu item from the context menu)
3. correctly word a message to send to AxCrypt on what i'm trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1*. determine if the executable i've entered is the right one for the
    context menu selection in windows

**Run [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and check the path used to launch the exe is correct - otherwise you'll see whats wrong.**

*2*.   correctly run this process and feed it the file argument for the
    file that i clicked on (as if i had chosen their menu item from the
    context menu)

```
string args = String.Format(@"{0}", "A File Arg");
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
```

*3*.   correctly word a message to send to AxCrypt on what i'm trying to
    do!

**Send them a link to this SO Q & A**

Comment: cool i'm errors now from `AxCrypt` now so it's a start. i'll need to find out from them what the correct arguments are and the format. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Look this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Vitor\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "olaa";
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pProcess.Start();
        string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pProcess.WaitForExit();
```